# Error in using Case Expression in select statement while we used join in statements

Tags: sql, oracle, case, column-alias

This code doesn't work and showing error "From keyword not found where expected"

```
select m.marks,
CASE 
WHEN m.marks<65 then 'F' 
WHEN m.marks>65 then 'P' 
END m.grade 
from student s INNER JOIN marks m ON s.id=m.id;
```

But this works

```
select marks, 
CASE 
WHEN marks<65 then 'F' 
WHEN marks>65 then 'P' 
END grade 
from marks
```

Comment: Who betide those who are in the purgatory of marks of 65.

Answer (score 1):

The `m` is an alias for the `marks` table, and you use that when referencing columns in that table. You are applying it to a column alias:

```
END m.grade
```

where it does not belong, so - in that place only - remove the `m.`:

```
select m.marks,
CASE 
WHEN m.marks<65 then 'F' 
WHEN m.marks>65 then 'P' 
END grade 
from student s INNER JOIN marks m ON s.id=m.id;
```

As @Gordon pointed out in a comment, you are checking >65 and <65, so a student with *exactly* 65 will not get either F or P - the grade for them will be null. You probably want:

```
WHEN m.marks < 65 then 'F' 
WHEN m.marks >= 65 then 'P'
```

or

```
WHEN m.marks >= 65 then 'P' 
ELSE 'F'
```

... though if `marks` is null the second version will treat that as F too, while the first will still return null.

Comment: Thank you , I got it that here after End it is an column alias. so it should not contain table alias ... thank you

Comment: @saikumar - I've added a note about the missing grade for exactly 65 marks that Gordon referred to in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You cant use a column value as column Alias

```
Select 1 AS Alias_1,
CASE 
WHEN 1=1 THEN 1
WHEN 2=2 THEN 2
END AS Alias_2_AnyName
from dual d;
```

If you use

```
Select 1 AS Alias_1,
CASE 
WHEN 1=1 THEN 1
WHEN 2=2 THEN 2
END AS d.value
from dual d;
```

Oracle is expecting an Alias Name after your case block end, but instead you are adding another column value(As key could be omitted)

Comment: Hey tq.. I got it

Answer (score 0):

`m.grade` is the issue, it should be just `grade`  as it is an alias

```
select m.marks,
CASE 
WHEN m.marks<65 then 'F' 
WHEN m.marks>65 then 'P' 
END grade 
from student s INNER JOIN marks m ON s.id=m.id;
```